# WHERE with IN-operator but starts-with instead of full-match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a case with a table .

```
[ I D  ]  [ n a m e ] [ 2 ID]
310000    Kikiriki    100001
310010    Mandalina   100002
210000    Keyboard    200001
310020    Maouse      100003
012001    PC          NULL
```

With `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [2 ID] IN ('310000','012001')`   i get only results from 310000  and 012001. I need  results of all ID that starts with 310% or 012%.

```
AND Mat_FinDok_KontoPr2 like '310%'
AND Mat_FinDok_KontoPr2 like '012%'
AND Mat_FinDok_Dobavuvac LIKE '%'
AND Mat_FinDok_TipDok LIKE '000005%'
AND Mat_FinDok_DataDok BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'

Result 0 Rows
```

and with this

```
AND mat_findok.Mat_FinDok_KontoPr2 IN ('310000', '012001')
AND mat_findok.Mat_FinDok_Dobavuvac LIKE '%'
AND Mat_FinDok_Dobavuvac LIKE '%'
AND Mat_FinDok_TipDok LIKE '000005%'
AND Mat_FinDok_DataDok BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'

Result 11 Rows
```

But here i dont have results from `012002`.

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should write the query to get what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE id like '310%' or id like '012%';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIKE` with the `%` wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id LIKE '310%' OR Id LIKE '012%'
```

---

[T-SQL Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: Correct - you can't use wildcards with the `IN` operator.